# PHP getting name of file using class

Tags: php, class, oop

How do I find the name of a file using a class?
For example:
index.php

```
include 'class.php'
$class = new class();
```

How would you find the file (in this example index.php) inside of class.php?

Comment: sadly no, that just returns class.php

Comment: Magic constant `__FILE__` return the full path and filename of the file http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: @user3426581 you want to list each files who use the classname "class"?

Comment: not really each file, just the file currently using it

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that you need to know the file name where a particular class is used at runtime. It sounds like an unusual situation. I am interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$class = new MyClass();
$class->file = __FILE__;
```

You could pass it to the constructor if you define your class accordingly

```
class MyClass {

    public $file;

    public function __construct($file){
        $this->file = $file;
    }

$class = new MyClass(__FILE__);
```

Comment: Works for me, what are you trying to do with it? Note that class is a reserved name in PHP and you shouldn't name a class "class".